# WSTP requires to create link

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am trying to compile the codes in C++ using WSTP in Windows OS. 
The code can be compiled however it requires me to create a link.

[image]

I have tried options like placing the necessary dll in the source code directory, included wstp32i4.lib in the Resouce Files and wstp.h in the Header Files.

Have I missed some steps or are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Could you tell the steps you are following to compile the code?

Comment: You would get the same behavior by launching one of the prebuilt examples, like `addtwo.exe`, since it is meant to be used via [`Install`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Install.html) which takes care of establishing the link.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal behaviour for [installable MathLink programs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InstallingExistingWSTPCompatiblePrograms.html).  Instead of running them directly, use them with [`Install`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Install.html).

```
Install["/path/to/your/prog"]
```